# Embed FLV or SWF files on a webpage in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I have been working on this for a while and there doesn't seem to be a clear cut working example. I am having trouble embedding flash videos (.flv or .swf) into a webpage. My skill level in the video / web department is not all that great. Here's what I am using.

- IE 9
- swfObject
- Either VLC player or FLV player or JW player

I am not sure how to accomplish this. Not sure whether to use  or  or both, as everyone on the web has different opinions and ideas on how it should work.

If anyone could help explain this better to me and possibly even provide a working example, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? HTML: 
[`Embed` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) [`object` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

Comment: I've tried everything and many variations of using the <embed> tag and <object> tag together or separately. Through recent developments, I'm looking to see if this can be accomplished with javascript. My research has lead me to believe that the swfObject integrates will with javascript